# How to use Java 8 Streams to calculate running balance

Tags: java, java-stream

Please help me convert following calculation to streams

I have list of Transactions

```
class Transaction
{
  String id;
  Double amount;
  Double balance;
}

before calculation / input

amount   balance
100.0    null
-50.0    null
100.0    null
-100.0   null
200.0    null
```

I am doing following operation to calculate original balance before each transaction happened. Note negative transaction means money added to the account

```
  @Test
    public void runningBalanceWithoutUpdatingCurrent(){
        Double current=300d;
        for (int i = 0; i < transactions.size(); i++) {
            Transaction transaction = transactions.get(i);
           if(i==0)
            transaction.setBalance(current + transaction.getAmount());
           else
               transaction.setBalance(transactions.get(i-1).getBalance()+transaction.getAmount());
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("calculated");
        print(transactions);
    }
```

And i have the output as follows

```
calculated

amount   balance
100.0    400.0
-50.0    350.0
100.0    450.0
-100.0   350.0
200.0    550.0
```

Comment: you should be able to do it with a reduce() call trivially

Answer (score 1):

There's not going to be much improved but you could use `IntStream` along with a `forEach` and do something as such:

```
public void runningBalanceWithoutUpdatingCurrent(){
        if(transactions.size() > 0){
            Transaction transaction = transactions.get(0);
            transaction.setBalance(300d + transaction.getAmount());
        }

        IntStream.range(1, transactions.size())
                 .forEach(i -> { 
                        Transaction t = transactions.get(i);
                        t.setBalance(transactions.get(i-1).getBalance() + t.getAmount());
                  });

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("calculated");
        print(transactions);
}
```